# Remove the webform for 'Username or email/Password

Tags: keycloak

We have a realm where access to clients will only be via Identity Providers. At the moment, the list of Identity Providers appear below the webform for 'Username or email/Password. Is there a way to remove the webform and only show the list of identity Providers?

What I have tried:

Experimented with changing the Authentication Flows in 'Browser'. Can't use the Flow 'Identity Provider Redirector' as it would be for a list of Identity Providers (not a specific one).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be done through Themes in Keycloak. You could make a custom theme that just doesn't show the username and password fields. Rob Ferguson made a two-part guide in which he shows how to make such a theme by yourself. In part 2 is a part called "FreeMarker templates". There he shows that you can change the input fields and everything, so you could try just leaving these out.

So my solution:
Make a custom theme based on the theme that you want to use and just leave the two inputs out.

Link to the guide:

- [Keycloak Themes - Part 1](https://robferguson.org/blog/2020/04/12/keycloak-themes-part-1/)
- [Keycloak Themes - Part 2](https://robferguson.org/blog/2020/04/17/keycloak-themes-part-2/)

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated. I was mistaken in that it was via a configuration a setting in the 'Authentication Flow'.